# Query on Django model to get only one response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

My get endpoint is this:

```
def get(self, request, name, rollno):
        """Display latest infomation"""
        schema = models.CredentialOffer.objects.filter(name= name, rollno= rollno)
        serializer = serializers.CredentialOfferSerializer(schema, many=True)
        #serializer = self.serializer_class()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Myurl
`path("records/<str:name>/<str:rollno>", views.TestApiView.as_view()),`
so it is displaying data with name and roll no i passed. 
ex: http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/records/lucky/1234

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "lucky",
        "rollno": "1234",
        "comment": "test1",
        "responseStatus": "SUCCESS"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "lucky",
        "rollno": "1234",
        "comment": "test2",
        "responseStatus": "SUCCESS"
    }
```

If their are multiple records, how do i modify view.py to display only one record(record having highest id among them) where id is auto generated field of model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the [**`.latest(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) one with respect to the `pk`. Furthermore you should remove the `many=True` parameter, since now you are processing a single object:

```
def get(self, request, name, rollno):
    """Display latest infomation"""
    schema = models.CredentialOffer.objects.filter(
        name=name,
        rollno=rollno
    ).latest('pk')
    # no many=True
    serializer = serializers.CredentialOfferSerializer(schema)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```